# How to append {% include %} to html using js?

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-templates

I wan to include `post.html` template inside of `home.html` template, to do this I use jquery to append `{% include "post.html" %}` to `home.html` template.

The thing is that it appears in `home.html` like `{% include "post.html" %}` without being evaluated into the acutal `post.html` content and that's the problem I want to use:

```js
$('body').append('{%include "post.html"%}')
```

to add the post.html to home.html but in home.html all i get is:

```
<!--home.html-->
{%include "post.html"%}
```

What I expect is:

```
<!--home.html-->
<div>actual content of post.html</div>
```

Comment: The django framework generates the page based on your templates and then sends it to the browser. At that point the browser executes your javascript. Django is no longer involved and the browser does not (and can not) understand django template markup.

Comment: @Kemp hmm, can you recommend me another way to pass template to another? or any way which help achieve wut i want ?

Comment: Unfortunately I only used django a long time ago and didn't do anything too in depth so I can't remember/don't know the detail, but it sounds like you just need to put the include directly into `home.html` rather than trying to dynamically do it later (unless you need it to be dynamic for whatever reason, at which point you're past what I can remember/know).

Comment: Just put it in the actual template. If it's not always needed, wrap it in an `{% if %}` statement.

Comment: @michjnich wut keeps me from doing this is the blocks inside the template is fetched by json requests whick i can't use it outside js in an easy way !

Comment: It kind of sounds like you have the wrong approach to whatever underlying problem you are trying to solve. If you want to replace chunks of html from the front end though, you could try `htmx`

Comment: @michjnich i googled it and matched wut i wanted, thanks